# Tooltipster で生成する HTML 内に、外部 JavaScript を使用してデータ（テキスト）を読み込ませたい

Tags: javascript

はじめまして。

私は、[Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) を使用してツールチップを表示させています。
問題は、Tooltipster で生成する HTML 内に、外部 JavaScript を使用して外部データベースよりデータ（テキスト）を表示させることができないことです。
この外部 JavaScript は、通常の HTML 内であれば、正常に動いています。

ソースは以下です。
spanタグ内に、idで紐付けられたデータを引っ張ってくる仕組みの外部 JavaScript です。

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.dammy').tooltipster({content: $('<div>dammytext<span id="******"></span><a href="xxx.html">more…</a></div>')});
    });
</script>
```

外部 JavaScript は、申し訳ございませんが公開できません…
ですので、明快な解決は難しいかもですが、何かヒントだけでもいただければ…と思い投稿させていただきました。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問にあるソースではcontentのHTMLがべた書きされていますが、実際もこのようなJSをscriptタグで読み込んでいるのでしょうか。「表示させることができない」とありますが、ブラウザの開発者コンソールにエラーは出ているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

通常のHTMLの場合

1. HTMLが処理される。 (既に実態がある)
2. 外部JavaScriptがロードされて、(1)に作用する

提示されたサンプルの場合は

1. HTMLが構成される。(まだ実態がない)
2. 外部JavaScriptがロードされて、(1)に作用する
3. tooltipsterで.dammy要素にcontentが定義付けられる。
4. マウスオーバー時に、(3)で定義された要素が**動的に**生成される (ここで実態化する)

となりますので(2)の時点で(3)の定義に作用させることができません。
おそらくこれが問題になっているのだと推測できます。
※ 動的生成が原因ならば。おそらくonload時のdocument.writeでも同様の現象が起こるはずです。

```
<section style="display:none;">
  <div id="a1">dammytext<span id="******"></span><a href="xxx.html">more…</a></div>
</section >
```

としておいて

```
$('.dammy').tooltipster({content: $('#a1')});
```

みたいな感じでもいけるのですが。tooltipsterで用意されているfunctionInit、functionBefore、functionReady、functionAfterあたりの設定項目も検討してください。

追伸：
content: $('#a1')みたいな指定した場合。#a1要素がツールチップ初回時に、まるっと切り取られて、tooltipsterの内部データとして取り込まれる動作のようです。ご注意ください。

Comment: 丁寧にご回答いただきありがとうございます。
おかげで問題を解消することができました。
もう少しHTMLの動的生成について理解しなければならないと痛感いたしました。 本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: @goemon 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers